# Calllable and exception handling

Tags: java, android, exception, threadpool, callable

I'm using a ThreadPool Executor and i invoke the tasks with invokeAll() method. In the callable call() method i write to a database but i only wanna write if i'm sure that the thread executed fine and didn't  terminate badly.

Does any of this solutions works:

### Solution 1

#### I think this don't work because thread can be interrupted after the database write so it doesn't return the result, i guess.

```
public Result call() throws exception(){

    ...

    if( !Thread.currentThread.isInterrupted() ){
       //Save to the database
    } 

    ...

    return result;
}
```

### Solution 2

#### Handle the writes after the get() method to be sure that it terminated well, if i understood correctly the get() method re-throws any exception caught during the execution

```
...

for( Future f : futures){

   try {

       Result r = f.get();

       //Do the write with the result i got
   }
   catch( Exception e){
     //Something went wrong
   }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In the callable call() method i write to a database ...

In that case, the exception handling logic needs to be in the `call()` method itself; e.g.

```
public Result call() {
    try {
       ...
       if (!Thread.currentThread.isInterrupted()) {
          // Save to the database
          return result;
       } else {
          return // some result that means interrupted.
       }
    catch (Exception ex) {
       return // some result that means failed.
    }
}
```

There doesn't seem to be any point in trying to get the main thread to do the database save.

Comment: @Sthepen Thanks i think that solves the problem, it makes more sense to handle the exception in call method yes. Im thinking that with your example even if i write to the database and and exception occurs after that, i can still rollback the operation in the catch block if i need to.